# How to emulate request scope behavior in session scope bean?

Tags: java, jsf

In my jsf application I have a button for sending mail. And each time it clicked I want to show message that mail was or wasn't sent.

This is a typical request-scope functionality. But the problem is that I have 1 backing bean with session scope now. And all data is in this bean. And method 'send' referred by action attribute of the button is in this bean.

So, what is the way out? If I should create one more request-scope bean then how should I refer to it from my session bean?

Comment: Request scoped data belongs in the request scope. Session scoped data belongs in the session scope. It can't be that more clear/obvious. In other words: refactor.

Comment: I need to send by mail data from session scope (I can't put them to the request scope). But the result message should be in request scope (because I want to see it only one time just after sending mail). What can I refactor?

Comment: I realize, if it's **only** the messaging, then you can also just grab `FacesMessage`. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach, you can make use of [`FacesMessage`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html) here which you add to the context using [`FacesContext#addMessage()`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#addMessage%28java.lang.String,%20javax.faces.application.FacesMessage%29). FacesMessages are request based and likely more suited for the particular functional requirement than some custom messaging approach.

Here's an example of the bean action method:

```
public void sendMail() {
    FacesMessage message;
    try {
        Mailer.send(from, to, subject, message);
        message = new FacesMessage("Mail successfully sent!");
    } catch (MailException e) {
        message = new FacesMessage("Sending mail failed!");
        logger.error("Sending mail failed!", e); // Yes, you need to know about it as well! ;)
    }
    FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().addMessage(null, message);
}
```

With a `null` clientId the message becomes "global", so that you can make use of the following construct to display *only* global messages:

```
 <h:messages globalOnly="true" />
```

**Update:** to have the success and error message displayed in a different style, play with the [`FacesMessage.Severity`](http://java.sun.com/javaee/5/docs/api/javax/faces/application/FacesMessage.html#field_summary):

```
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_INFO, "Mail successfully sent!", null);
    } catch (MailException e) {
        message = new FacesMessage(FacesMessage.SEVERITY_ERROR, "Sending mail failed!", null);
```

.. in combination with `infoClass/infoStyle` and `errorClass/errorStyle` in `h:messages`:

```
 <h:messages globalOnly="true" infoStyle="color:green" errorStyle="color:red" />
```

Comment: I've already found a workaround. I have a request-scope bean and I pass my session-scoped bean to it with propertyActionListener. Request-scoped bean calls send() method in session-scoped bean. Your solution is obviously better because it's even difficult to explain mine.

Comment: It's clear enough, I already understood it when you said propertyActionListener.

Answer (score 1):

Either:

- just push the message onto the request scope from the `send` method (via the `ExternalContext`)
- refactor the method to a request-scope bean and inject any session information it needs (the managed bean framework can do this)